# oraInventory issues on solaris

Tags: solaris, oracle-11g

I have created a script to install oracle 11g on Solaris. My script works 100% well on solaris 10/13, but fails on 10 9/10.

The install logs are exactly the same up until this point:

```
INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations 
INFO: Completed background operations 
INFO: Executing action at state showSummary
INFO: Reading shiphome metadata from  /export/home/database/install/../stage/shiphomeproperties.xml 
INFO:Loading beanstore from file:/export/home/database/install/../stage/shiphomeproperties.xml
INFO: Translating external format into raw format  
INFO: Restoring class oracle.install.driver.oui.ShiphomeMetadata from
file:/export/home/database/install/../stage/shiphomeproperties.xml
INFO: size estimation for EEinstall is 4664.178535461426 INFO: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Disk space : required 4.55 GB available 208.88 GB 
Source location : /export/home/database/install/../stage/products.xml 
Install method : Advanced installation 
Database edition : Enterprise Edition (Create and configure a database) 
Oracle base : /opt/app/oracle Software
location : /opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 
OSDBA group : oinstall
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration : General Purpose / Transaction Processing 
Globaldatabase name : orcl 
Oracle system identifier (SID) : luxsuppdb
Allocated memory : 6000 MB
```

The version that works also has this part:

```
INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO:  
INFO: Inventory location : /opt/app/oraInventory 
INFO: oraInventory group : oinstall 
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which is missing from the one that is not working.

Does someone have any clue what I could be missing? I can post the script too if necessary. They are both using the same install script, same install files and same db.rsp.

Comment: Are you sure that 11g is supported on Solaris 10 9/10?

Comment: Oracle documentation says it needs Solaris Update 4+, as per: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24191_01/common/install/system_requirements.html